# Compiling LaTeX in pedantic mode

Tags: errors, compiling, warnings

Some compilers for general purpose programming languages such as GCC have a switch for turning warnings into actual errors:

> $ gcc -Werror main.c

There is a similar mechanism for compiling LaTeX documents?

Comment: TeX warnings can't be turned into errors without changing the program (which I wouldn't dare). LaTeX errors *could* be turned into errors, but I can't see why.

Comment: @egreg: We can learn **a lot** by simply giving warnings their merit.

Comment: Nowadays many people run TeX via a front-end that calls the program with `\nonstopmode`; and many people don't even look at errors! This site is full of examples. `;(`

Comment: @egreg -- there are a few latex warnings that could reasonably be considered errors -- `Float too large for page ...`, `Command \xxx invalid in math mode`, `Label xxx multiply defined` -- but something like `There were undefined references` is hardly fatal, and in fact expected on a first run.  what would be nice is the ability to "classify" warnings by severity level, and allow a run-time decision on whether or not to stop if a "serious" one is issued.

Comment: @barbarabeeton With LaTeX3 messages can be redirected.

Comment: @egreg -- good to know.  unfortunately, we're not likely to be using latex3 for some time, but it's something to plan for.

Comment: Perhaps this could be done through some third-party build manager. (`latexmk` and `rubber` come to mind.)

Comment: Actually it is the `-Werror` option which turns warnings into errors, not `-pendatic`.

Comment: @giordano, you're totally right.

Comment: Learn from warnings? No way, we are humans. `:)` On a more serious note, as Sean suggested, we can do some postprocessing; there are warnings that might be relevant, but others simply are context-based (say, when labels and refs are not set yet); writing a filter seems reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically two classes of warnings issued by LaTeX; those issued by the typesetting engine, for instance

```
Overfull \hbox (153.62823pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--10
```

and warning issued by LaTeX, for instance

```
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 275.0pt on input line 17.
```

The first kind of warning can't be turned into an error message without changing TeX (the program), which I wouldn't dare.

For the second kind it's theoretically possible by something like

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericWarning}[2]{%
  \GenericError{#1}{#2}{}{Warning turned into error}}
```

so that the preceding warning becomes something like

```
! LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 275.0pt.


Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \end{table}

? h
Warning turned into error
```

where I show also the result of typing `h` at the error prompt.

For LaTeX3 a more general redirection facility is in the works.